# "it is important" or "it important"

Tags: grammar

Could you please explain why "it is important" is correct but "it important" is wrong as below?

> I should remember it important to try everything.
> I should remember that it is important to try everything.

Comment: You can *consider* it important to try everything, or *think* it important, but *remember it important* is not idiomatic.  Verbs are not identical but license different complements.

Answer (score 4):

The words "*it important*" can be correct, just not after the verb "remember".

Some verbs allow for the structure *[ verb + "it" + complement + "to" + base form ]*, such as:

> I *consider* it bad luck to step on a beetle.
> I *think* it important to arrive at a party with a gift.

The meaning of these sentences are:

> I consider stepping on a beetle (to be) bad luck.
> I think arriving at a party with a gift is important.

This structure only works with certain verbs, and "remember" isn't one of them. I believe all the verbs that use this structure are *verbs of opinion*, and we don't use "remember" to express opinions.

Answer (score 0):

1. *I should remember it important to try everything.*
2. *I should remember that it is important to try everything.*

Example 1 may be interpreted as elliptical with an implied *as*, thus:  *I should remember it (as) important to try everything.* It can suggest that previously, I did not believe it was important to try everything, and suffered some consequence as a result. This statement may serve as a reminder or admonishment of that failure to avoid future trouble.

While example 2 might also be used similarly, it is not so confined, and could be a general statement of wisdom to color future actions.

This nuance is captured grammatically by which parts of the sentence are modified. In example 1, *important* assigns quality to the verb *remember* for *it*. In the second example, *important* assigns quality to the phrase (*to try everything*) through its alignment with the pronoun *it*. The whole clause (*that it is important to try everything*) functions as the object of the verb *remember*. This shift in focus slightly alters the meaning.

Using unusual syntax is one way for narrators to be more precise in what they want to emphasize in a particular situation. Sometimes, the presence of unexpected syntax, by itself, can indicate that there may be more information than initially meets the eye. Consider:

1. *I should remember it important to try everything; this blunder nearly ruined my reputation.*
2. *I should remember that it is important to try everything and never to give up.*